# Problems with SSR and Firebase in the latest SvelteKit release

Tags: firebase, vite, sveltekit

In my last project with SvelteKit, I used firebase without any problems just by doing this:
(I don't use ts, only javascript)
**svelte.config.js:**

```js
import adapter from '@sveltejs/adapter-auto'

/** @type {import('@sveltejs/kit').Config} */
const config = {
    kit: {
        vite: {
            server: {
                fs: true
            }
        },
        adapter: adapter()
    }
}

export default config
```

In the latest version, some things have changed, I tried to configure as I had done before but I got a warning that the configurations are now done in **vite.config.js**

I tried to do the same thing as before, but it is generating this error:

```
failed to load module for ssr: ../../../firebase.config
Error: failed to load module for ssr: ../../../firebase.config
    at instantiateModule (file:///C:/Users/rcap/Documents/svelte/bot-imoveis/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-1513d487.js:50250:15)
```

How can I solve it?

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem, and my solution was to remove the old node modules and lock files using `rm -rf node_modules package-lock.json` in the terminal. Then I reinstalled those files with `npm i`

I don't know if this is an ideal solution, but it fixed the problem on my end.

Comment: This worked for me after downgrading from fireabse v10 to v9