# How to fix "failed to load module for ssr: ../environment.js" after SvelteKit migration

Tags: sveltekit

**The Problem**

While migrating my SvelteKit project to the latest version, I'm encountering the following error

```
Error: failed to load module for ssr: ../environment.js
    at instantiateModule (file:///Users/userName/projectFolder/projectName/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-557f29e6.js:53336:15)
```

**What I Did**

I followed the migration instructions located [here](https://github.com/sveltejs/kit/discussions/5774).

1. I ran `npx svelte-migrate routes` inside my terminal to start the migration
2. I replaced `$app/env` with `$app/environment` throughout my project
3. I installed the latest version of `vite`
4. Made sure I had the latest version of `SvelteKit` installed.

**Similar StackOverflow question for reference**

[Problems with SSR and Firebase in the latest SvelteKit release](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73081133/problems-with-ssr-and-firebase-in-the-latest-sveltekit-release/73819955?noredirect=1#comment130348873_73819955)

Though the location of this person's problem is different, at the core, they are very similar. Any insight into what I can do to resolve this issue would be greatly appreciated.